# Build variable that contains the absolute path to _PublishedWebsites\{ProjectName}.zip

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I have a asp .net project which post build creates the packages as

```
<vNext build directories>\Bin\Release\_PublishedWebsites\{ProjectName}.zip
```

I want to get the absolute path till the .zip file into a variable. i can get the path till

```
<vNext build directories>\Bin\Release\_PublishedWebsites
```

but not the last part, which always contains the `<project name>.zip`.

If i can get the project name in a variable that is also fine, or if i can get the absolute path directly will be perfect.

Please help me, let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a variable for a project name by default. You can only create a variable and assign a value to it. Then you can use variable $(ProjectName) for project name:

[image]

Comment: can we access this variable somehow from the vNext def MSBuildProjectName

Comment: Do you mean you want to assign variable $(ProjectName) to MSBuildProjectName Property? No, the "MSBuildProjectName" property name is reserved.

Comment: no i meant to use the MSBuildProjectName variable data and pass it as vNext powershell argument.

Comment: Build definition can't recognize MSBuildProjectName Property. This Property only uses in MSBuild. There is no default way to get project name in a variable.

Comment: I was looking for something similar that we used to have in XAML builds:
serverBuildProjectItem

Comment: The new build system is completely different from XAML build system,  XAML build activities won't work in the new build system. There is no default way to get project name in a variable. As an alternative, you can add a custom build task to get project name set it as a variable, then powershell step is able to get it.